# Getting a SIGABRT while loading data

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently making my second app, or first without a tutorial. This app is built for the purpose of managing money and one of the features is that you can record past transactions. I have gotten it capable of showing the past information but at this point it has stopped accessing information properly.

Whenever I try to access data from a few of the forKeys it gives me a SIGABRT. I have looked through this for quite a while and could not find anything

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource 
{

let defaults = UserDefaults.standard;

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var subViewREC: UIView!

public var dates = [""]
public var names = [""]
public var costs = [""]
public var IDs:[Int] = [0]
public var oldID:Int = 0

var refresher:UIRefreshControl!


//--------------------------making cells-------------------------------
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return(names.count);
}
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! customCell;


    cell.name?.text = names[indexPath.row];
    cell.cost?.text = "cost:\t" + costs[indexPath.row];
    cell.date?.text = dates[indexPath.row];


    return(cell);
}





//----------------------------------view did load--------------------------
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    subViewREC.isHidden = true;


    refresher = UIRefreshControl()
    refresher.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SecondViewController.populate), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    tableView.addSubview(refresher)
```

this is where the actual problem seems to occur, while loading a new value for dates and the rest:

```
    dates = defaults.object(forKey: "dateMemory") as! [String];
    names = defaults.object(forKey: "nameMemory") as! [String];
    costs = defaults.object(forKey: "costMemory") as! [String];
    IDs = defaults.object(forKey: "ID") as! [Int];
    oldID = defaults.object(forKey: "oldID") as! Int;
    populate()
}

//----------------------------populate tableview-----------------------
func populate()
{

    tableView.reloadData();
    refresher.endRefreshing();
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}
```

It actually works once after if I set the data to some set of data while the app is not on this view, but I cannot just reset the data every other time I run the app or it would be useless for recording long term

Comment: You shouldn't be using UserDefaults for this type of data storage, I'd recommend using Realm or CoreData

Comment: Don't use `as!`.  Test whether you have the value/type you expect -- or any -- rather than using a forced unwrap.